# Search records from previous day

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date

I am trying to retrieve records from an ORACLE table that have yesterday's date in one of its column. I have a job running everyday retrieving ONLY yesterday's records.

NOTE** the column insert_date is of type `date`

These are the two SQL statements I have so far:

```
SELECT distinct column1
  FROM table1
 WHERE flag = 'N'  
   AND insert_date BETWEEN TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE-1) AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) 
   AND ipaddress IS NOT NULL
   AND ipaddress <> '0.0.0.0';
```

and

```
SELECT distinct column1 
  FROM table1
 WHERE flag = 'N'  
   AND insert_date 
       BETWEEN To_Timestamp(CONCAT (to_char(CURRENT_DATE-1),' 12:00:00 AM')) 
           AND To_Timestamp(Concat (to_char(CURRENT_DATE-1),' 11:59:59 PM')) 
   AND ipaddress IS NOT NULL 
   AND ipaddress <> '0.0.0.0';
```

It seems as these two SQL statements produce the same output. However, I am no expert in ORACLE so I would like to ask the community if there is any 'gotchas' that I am not aware of.

Comment: looks like you are accounting for the 'gotcha' =- which is that you want the day to start at midnight - not just one day ago (including minutes)

Comment: I was hoping to use the first sql since performs much quicker compared to the second sql. I am assuming it is because there is a partition by range on the insert_date column

Comment: just a thought on the other part but rather than checking ipaddress twice how about nvl(ipaddress, '0.0.0.0') <> '0.0.0.0' unless of course there are indexing issues with this for that column.

Comment: Since I wanted to use the first sql in my post, I made a minor change to avoid the '12am' record being a part of the previous day.

Here is the sql:

    `SELECT distinct column1
    FROM table1
    WHERE flag = 'N'  
       AND insert_date BETWEEN TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE-1) AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) - 1/86400
       AND ipaddress IS NOT NULL
       AND ipaddress <> '0.0.0.0';`


I substract a second (1/24*60*60) from trunc(current_date) to get [CURRENT_DATE-1 11:59:59PM].

Thanks all for the tips and info to making sure I was playing it safe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the between but subtract a second from the end date.

```
insert_date between trunc(CURRENT_DATE-1) and trunc(CURRENT_DATE) - 1/86400
```

Comment: we have over 50 mil records. this will severely impact the performance if I truncated insert_date

Comment: Replaced my previous answer to account for the large data set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct column1
 FROM table1
 WHERE flag = 'N'  AND
  insert_date = trunc(sysdate-1,'DD')
   and ipaddress is not null and ipaddress<>'0.0.0.0';
```

Your first query works fine but you may not need to use `between` when you want to filter the data for a single day.

Answer (score 0):

```
to_Timestamp(Concat (to_char(CURRENT_DATE-1),' 12:00:00 AM'))
```

is very superfluous, and I assume that's the reason for the other approach (`trunc(current_date-1)`)

Only "gotcha" I can see is that a record with a date of *exactly* 12:00:00am would be included in the second query but not the first.

There's a pretty easy way to check for any issues of this sort:

```
SELECT distinct column1
FROM table1
WHERE flag = 'N'  AND insert_date between trunc(CURRENT_DATE-1)
    and trunc(CURRENT_DATE) and ipaddress is not null and ipaddress<>'0.0.0.0';
MINUS
SELECT distinct column1 
FROM table1
WHERE flag = 'N'  
      AND insert_date between To_Timestamp(Concat (to_char(CURRENT_DATE-1),' 12:00:00 AM'))                         and To_Timestamp(Concat (to_char(CURRENT_DATE-1),' 11:59:59 PM')) 
      and ipaddress is not null and ipaddress<>'0.0.0.0';
```

and

```
SELECT distinct column1 
FROM table1
WHERE flag = 'N'  
      AND insert_date between To_Timestamp(Concat (to_char(CURRENT_DATE-1),' 12:00:00 AM'))                         and To_Timestamp(Concat (to_char(CURRENT_DATE-1),' 11:59:59 PM')) 
      and ipaddress is not null and ipaddress<>'0.0.0.0';
MINUS
SELECT distinct column1
FROM table1
WHERE flag = 'N'  AND insert_date between trunc(CURRENT_DATE-1)
    and trunc(CURRENT_DATE) and ipaddress is not null and ipaddress<>'0.0.0.0';
```

If you get results from either of these queries, then it means that two approaches are not exactly equal.